# Creating a windows service that runs an endless loop

Tags: c#, windows-services

I only do web development using MVC4 so I haven't really worked with Windows services.  I am trying to create a service that will query my database every 5 seconds and check for specific results.  If results come up then run my custom code.  I originally tried doing this in my Global.asax file using the Timer class which I found it is a bad practice:

```
var timer = new Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Callback);
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

I was told that a Windows service would be best for this problem.  Are there any tutorials or code snippets out there?

UPDATE:

Sorry I realize that was vague.

Im just looking for the best possible way to check my database to see if any of my records have hit their "end time" (imagine creating an auction and setting an end time for it, so when the auction ends i can send an email out notifying the user). I tried this using the Timer in my global.asax but i know there are plenty of problems with that, so i was suggested by another user to create a windows service, is that correct? if so where can i look to get started on that

Comment: Might be more efficient to use a database trigger than hitting your DB every 5 seconds..

Comment: what happened when you searched?

Comment: Did you mean in your question that using a Timer at all was bad, or that doing it in the global.asax of an MVC web app was bad?

Comment: @hatchet sorry if i was vague.. Im just looking for the best possible way to check my database to see if any of my records have hit their "end time"  (imagine creating an auction and setting an end time for it, so when the auction ends i can send an email out notifying the user).  I tried this using the Timer in my global.asax but i know there are plenty of problems with that, so i was suggested by another user to create a windows service, is that correct? if so where can i look to get started on that

Comment: Don't know much about this type of programming, but traditionally in c programming one would use a while loop to do an endless loop.   while (1 == 1) { do stuff }

Comment: Is it that time critical to send email every 5 seconds? Your records that expire have an expire time. You can make a service that runs once every 15 minutes, queries all expired records since last check, then sends batch of emails. Alternatively, you can create a SQL Agent job that does the same thing and uses SQL email to send emails out. Since this process is independent of the web application, I agree that it's not a good idea to put such logic anywhere in the web app, including global.asax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to sure at the complexity that you are going for, but here is a simple template that you could play around with and see what happens:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace MyService
{
   public class MyWindowsService:ServiceBase
   {
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    private static System.Timers.Timer scheduledTimer;

    public MyWindowsService()
    {
        ServiceName = "MyService";
        //Additional Initilizing code.
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new MyWindowsService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        scheduledTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        scheduledTimer.AutoReset = true;
        scheduledTimer.Enabled = true;
        scheduledTimer.Interval = 5000;
        scheduledTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(scheduledTimer_Elapsed);
        scheduledTimer.Start();
    }

    void scheduledTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //DO CHECK.
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (scheduledTimer != null)
        {
            scheduledTimer.Stop();
            scheduledTimer.Elapsed -= scheduledTimer_Elapsed;
            scheduledTimer.Dispose();
            scheduledTimer = null;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "MyService";
    }
}
```